# Video streaming Using Django, JS, HTML, Ajax

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, xmlhttprequest, video-streaming

I am trying to make a video streaming website

Currently i have made one and that one uses the resource as this
[Here you can see that it is loading under media tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d479r.png)

but i want to stream using a method like Youtube Uses (using xhr/ajax)
[as you can see here all the video data is being loaded using xhr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPqT7.png)

for this i tried using method described in this article
https://medium.com/canal-tech/how-video-streaming-works-on-the-web-an-introduction-7919739f7e1

but i doesn't work